# Litecoin /Bitcoin addresses

Tags: litecoin

I have just bought some Litecoin and Bitcoin. There are many addresses that seem to be created as I press Send and Receive.
Do I need to allocate one of those generate addresses to my purchased Coin or can I just press Send and put the Recipient address. What happens when I put my email address ?

I'm so bad at this.
Thanks
Chris

Comment: Litecoin and Bitcoin addresses are in no way shared.

No need for your email address, this is just a label.

Which wallet software are you using?

Comment: Scott,I will get Trezor very soon but only purchased a VERY small number of Litecoins until I get my head around it. You guys are so generous with your time. Appreciated, Chris

Answer (score 2):

If you're considering pasting your email as a public address to withdraw funds to, then I would recommend you search out some 'intro to bitcoin' or 'how to use bitcoin' videos on Youtube. I think watching a few of those will be quite helpful, at the very least they should provide you with enough knowledge to ask better questions. I'm not trying to be rude, but you're asking vague and wide questions about some very basic functions. Its OK to be 'bad at this', everyone starts there! With a bit of work, the system will seem less foreign to you very soon.

To take a stab at answering your Q more directly: Your wallet software can generate a million addresses, or more. Doing so doesn't really matter or accomplish anything, an address only 'becomes important' once you send bitcoin to it.

The coins you bought are probably sitting on an exchange service right now (I'm assuming you used something like Coinbase), so you probably want to withdraw them to a wallet you actually control. To do so, you'll install some wallet software, and it will generate some receiving addresses for you. Open up your exchange account, and paste one of the receiving addresses into the 'withdraw' field (it doesn't matter which address you paste in, just pick one from your wallet). Next you'll press submit/confirm, and after some time the exchange service should submit a transaction to the network to withdraw your coins.

Litecoin is a separate network, so you'll have to do the same thing again, but using litecoin software that will generate a litecoin receiving address for you.

If you try to withdraw to your email address (or anything else that isn't a valid bitcoin address), the wallet software will give you an error message, you will not be able to submit a transaction like that. The code is built to guard against errors.

Comment: @ "Litecoin is a separate network, so you'll have to do the same thing again, but using litecoin software that will generate a litecoin receiving address for you." I propose using the Trezor software to generate a litecoin receiving address.

Comment: @ChrisBorrett Glad I could help! A Trezor hardware wallet can handle both btc and ltc software, so that will work just fine. Bitcoin and Litecoin addresses look different, so it should be easy to tell which is which (and like I mentioned, if you mix them up, the software will give you an error and the coins will not send). Using a hardware wallet is a good decision, just make sure to store your seed phrase very securely! (do not store it digitally!)

Comment: Thanks again chytrik ...........have a great break.............Chris